# Joining two lines using Eyeshot

Tags: vb.net, eyeshot

I am just stating to use Eyeshot.  I would like to learn the method to join two line segments.  The documentation does not show a join but does of union on a region.  But I am unclear how the two lines can be a region.

Any help would be great.

```
    Cad1.Entities.Add(New Line(0, 0, 0, 96, 0, 0))
    Cad1.Entities.Add(New Line(96, 0, 0, 96, 48, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact they are not, `Region` entity requires closed contours.

Comment: I understand the code I post is not a Region mentioned it because regions is the only area I have have read about join or union.  Can you explain how one would go about joining the two line segments?